# How to set the ant working directory for an ant file within IntelliJ?

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

Surely this must be easy.  But nothing on the ant file config dialogs inside of intellij (10.5) has anything to do with working directories...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to configure it. Normally your script should be using paths relative to itself or some property.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I know the ant script should be written properly, but it's not and I have no control over changing.  It's part of a a convoluted build system.